How to obtain data from an IFRAME with Python and Selenium
I am trying to obtain a value from this page: https://www.bbva.com.co/personas/productos/inversion/fondos/pais.html
I the imagen, I show you what I need to obtain.
Inspected page
The first thing that I see is that this value is inside an Iframe with the class = "iframe_base ".
I tried the next code to extract the value, but it did not work properly, because I did not obtain nothing.
I am using selenium and the webdriver of Microsoft Edge.
What am I doing wrong? and How can I obtain what I need?
Thank´s.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
import time

# Configura el controlador de Edge
edge_options = Options()
# edge_options.add_argument("--headless") 
service = Service("C:/Users/PERSONAL/Downloads/msedgedriver.exe")  
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service, options=edge_options)

# Abre la página web
driver.get("https://www.bbva.com.co/personas/productos/inversion/fondos/pais.html")  # Reemplaza con la URL real

# Espera hasta que el iframe esté presente
time.sleep(5)  # Espera 5 segundos, ajusta según sea necesario

print("Seleccionamos el IFRAME")
iframe1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id = 'content-iframe_copy']")

print("Cambiamos el foco el IFRAME")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe1)

print("Obtener HTML del IFRAME")
html = driver.page_source
print(html)

print("Obtener el dato")
dato = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "g")
print(dato)

driver.quit()


u can use non selenium solution:
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*; q=0.01',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
}


def get_tsec() -> str:
    url = "https://www.bbva.es/ASO/TechArchitecture/grantingTickets/V02"
    payload = json.dumps({
        "authentication": {
            "consumerID": "30000032",
            "userID": "IMMH032",
            "authenticationType": "04",
            "authenticationData": [
                {
                    "authenticationData": [
                        "WAMH032P"
                    ],
                    "idAuthenticationData": "password"
                }
            ]
        }
    })
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    return response.headers['tsec']


def get_value(pair_name: str, tsec: str) -> float:
    url = f"https://www.bbva.es/ASO/management-entity-funds/v1/management-entities-funds/{pair_name}"
    headers['tsec'] = tsec
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    for x in response.json()['data']['netAssetValues']:
        if x['netAssetValueType']['id'] == 'LAST_DATE':
            return x['netAssetValueAmount']['amount']


print(get_value('CCAPAISCB', get_tsec()))

OUTPUT:
21128.849089


Thank you for your help. Could you share how do you did the structure of the code? or share some documentation related to it? Also could we, for example, click on a button in page in the same way you do the previous code?

@AXRG only dev tools in browser and postman

I don't have access to Edge but this works with Chrome and I imagine will work for Edge too.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

DRIVER_PATH = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"

options = Options()

service = Service(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.get("https://www.bbva.com.co/personas/productos/inversion/fondos/pais.html")

iframe = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#content-iframe_copy")

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

time.sleep(5)

price = driver.execute_script(
    """
    var shadowHost = document.querySelector('fichaco-page');
    var shadowRoot = shadowHost.shadowRoot;
    return shadowRoot.querySelector('.liquidativo-rentabilidad').textContent;
"""
)

print(price)

driver.quit()

The tricky component of this is that, yes, there is an <iframe> (and you were right to switch to it!) but the page included in the <iframe> has a shadow DOM. So you need to penetrate the shadow DOM to access the content inside.

Thank you for your help. I appreciate it. When I run the code I am obtaining this error:  "Message: javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'shadowRoot')" What do you think it is the problem? Postscript: I am opening the related page from Colombia.

you can use it
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

soup = BS(driver.page_source, features="html.parser")
step1 = soup.find("div", class_="caja-liquidativo-rentabilidad")
step2 = step1.find("p", class_="liquidativo-rentabilidad)"

